# .drawImage function is throwing a "TypeError: Image or Canvas expected", for canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, discord.js

I am trying to add a rank card in my discord bot, and in order to do so I am trying to use canvas but when I use canvas everything works fine until I hit the `.drawImage` method. Where it gives me an error saying "TypeError: Image or Canvas expected". Although I've already required `canvas` globally, and everything else that has to do with canvas works properly aswell.

I've tried to `require('canvas')` inside the function but that doesn't fix the problem either.

```js
const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(934, 282);
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const background = Canvas.loadImage('./images/Rank_Card.jpg');

ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);  
const attachment = new Discord.Attachment(canvas.toBuffer(), 'welcome-image.png');
msg.channel.send(`Testing...`, attachment);
```

When it sends the message it should attach the image with it, but right now its just giving me the following error.

Error:

```
C:\Users\Desktop\Discord\iBot\ibot.js:25
    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ^

TypeError: Image or Canvas expected
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[node-canvas' `loadImage()`](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas#loadimage) method returns a `Promise` which get resolved to an `<Image>`.

You can't pass this Promise directly, you'll have to *await* for it:

```
const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(934, 282);
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
// we need to await the Promise gets resolved since loading of Image is async
const background = await Canvas.loadImage('./images/Rank_Card.jpg');

ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);  
const attachment = new Discord.Attachment(canvas.toBuffer(), 'welcome-image.png');
msg.channel.send(`Testing...`, attachment);
```